# Why does this work? (Java, Graphics object)

Tags: java, text, graphics, instance, antialiasing

Here's my code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.drawString("This is my string", 200, 200);
}
```

This works correctly; the text comes out as anti-aliased. However, why does it work? The text is drawn by the g object, however as far as I can see, the anti-aliasing was turned on for the g2 object. How does the g object get it?

Comment: Because you made `g2` a reference to the `g` object.

Comment: `g` and `g2` are the same object, you just casted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Both **g** and **g2** are references to the same object (g). g refers to the object as *Graphics2D* whereas g2 refers to the object as *Graphics2D*.

Comment: Thank you. So when you cast one object to another, you're not creating any new object? You're actually just "casting" the reference to the object?

Comment: That is correct. Your object here (g) is both an Graphics and a Graphics2D. Depending on the case you might need to use it as Graphics or Graphics2D.

Answer (score 1):

`g` and `g2` are both references to the same object. In runtime, the type of the reference doesn't really matter - you have that object run a method.